# Alternate method for caching mysql query (query_cache) on version above 8.0

Tags: mysql, cache, innodb, query, mysql8

On mysql version 8+ the query_cache support was removed.

I know why it is not a friendly thing with InnoDB when considering the CPU.

But I've some databases which really need this support where user repeat the same query in most cases.

Is it possible to restore query_cache or to achieve the caching via some other means.

Comment: Let's discuss some of the queries.  And show up `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It may lead to a workaround.

Comment: Also [on topic](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/922/are-questions-about-implementation-details-of-a-database-on-topic/923) and seen by more specialised experts [at our sister site for database administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-cache+mysql)

Comment: MariaDB still supports Query Cache function.